# Manage entity IDs with data fixtures

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, fixtures

I'm facing an issue with Doctrine Data Fixtures: When I insert some data using fixtures for running acceptance tests, can I somehow ensure that  particular entities are persisted are persisted with a particular ID?

For example, I create several sample users, then run an acceptance test editing one of the users. I need to know the user's ID for this test case.
What is the best practice to handle this?
Is it possible to hardcode IDs for some entities created by fixtures, or should I store generated IDs to a separate table, file etc. to find the requested entity? or is there any other best practice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You did not tag your question with Symfony but reading through here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#sharing-objects-between-fixtures might give you some ideas.

Comment: Well I didn't because I don't work with Symfony there :) I use Doctrine also for Nette framework. However, I finally ended up with this Symfony's approach, so thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

In our application, we're setting the entities into static properties of those fixtures, so they can be used from tests easily.

```php
class CategoryTestFixture
    extends \Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture
    implements 
        \Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface,
        \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface
{

    /** @var \My\Category */
    public static $fooCategory;

    /** @var \My\Category */
    public static $barCategory;

    /** @var \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface */
    private $container;

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        self::$fooCategory = new Category('Foo');
        $entityManager->persist(self::$fooCategory);

        self::$barCategory = new Category('Bar');
        $entityManager->persist(self::$barCategory);

        $entityManager->flush();
    }

    // you can inject the container,
    // so you can use your Facades in fixtures

    public function getContainer(): ContainerInterface
    {
        return $this->container;
    }

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

}
```

There are few important rules to this:

- Make sure you do not call `$em->clear()` in your fixtures, so you can directly use the entities in other fixtures classes.
- Call `$em->clear()` once the fixtures are loaded, so they don't affect your tests.
- Before every test, make copy of the prepared database and use that copy for your tests, not the "template database". So you can modify the data safely. It can be further optimised, but this is the most straightforward solution.
- Don't merge or try to register as managed the original fixtures in your tests.

Now that you have the fixtures created, you use them like this

```php
$id = CategoryTestFixture::$barCategory->getId();
```

Also, you can reference all their properties, not only ids. So if you'd let's say wanted to assert, that your api returned the correct categories, you could do it like this.

```php
$this->assertArraySubset([
    [
        'id' => CategoryTestFixture::$fooCategory->getId(),
        'name' => CategoryTestFixture::$fooCategory->getName(),
    ],
    [
        'id' => CategoryTestFixture::$barCategory->getId(),
        'name' => CategoryTestFixture::$barCategory->getName(),
    ]
], $apiResponseData);
```

and if you wanna modify the data just for one testcase, use the properties of the fixture to modify database and then clear EM aftewards, so you don't create side-effects with already-populated identity map in the entity manager.

```php
$barCategory = $entityManager->find(
    Category::class,
    CategoryTestFixture::$barCategory->getId()
);

$barCategory->setName('Another name');

$entityManager->flush();
$entityManager->clear();
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but I don't see how this is better than Symfony's references approach. I don't also quite get how clearing EM helps, shouldn't already loaded entities be already properly mapped by Doctrine, so that if I modify it from a reference, all other references ("referring variables") point to the same, modified entity?